# Span is displayed over each other when wrapping

Tags: html

See the image what is going on, apparently the padding is not counting when it wraps

[image]

How can I make it wrap without this behavior?

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 2):

Spans are not block elements, they are inline elements.  By definition, this means they will stay *in line* with the text.  They will not move or adjust vertically based on top/bottom padding/margin, nor will they affect the vertical placement of any other elements.  If you want your text to have more space from row to row, you need to set the text's `line-height` property.

Here is a demo that demonstrates the difference between a block and inline element and how you can adjust for your span heights:

http://jsfiddle.net/35fgV/

When you adjust the padding of a span, the padding is applied above/below the text, but will not adjust the position of the text or anything above or below it.  If you don't want the padding to overlap the lines above and below, you need to set a `line-height` property in that block of text (not necessarily the span, but anything in the same line of text, between `<br>` tags for instance.  A line of text will inherit the largest `line-height` of any element in the same line.